# Index on a rapidly changing column

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

MySQL schema-design.

1. Is adding index on rapidly changing column like "lastUpdatedOn" worth it ?
2. How to calculate tradeoff ?

Since the column will be rapidly changing i.e. on every save call, the database has to re-index i.e. alter b-tree as an additional cost on every save call. By calculating tradeoff, I wish to know (if possible) the cost in terms of reads/writes.

For example the cost b-tree alteration might be equivalent to 1 write operation in which case, the index on given column is only profitable if read:write ratio > 2:1 in the concerned application.

I understand the cost might not be expressible in terms of writes like in the example but in terms of DS both appear as O(lgn) + some IO, hence the analogy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether to have an index including a "rapidly changing column" *is* a tradeoff.

An `UPDATE` needs to delete one entry in an the index and add a new entry elsewhere in the index.

On the other hand, the index *may* greatly speed up due to the index.

Please provide a concrete example so we can discuss the tradeoffs further.

Regular non-`UNIQUE` indexes (as opposed to `FULLTEXT` and `SPATIAL`) are maintained thus:

There is a "change buffer" (qv) in the buffer_pool that maintains index updates that have not yet been written to disk.

When a `DELETE` occurs, an entry is added to the Change Buffer to say that the index entry needs to be removed.

For `UPDATE` two entries *may* need to be put into the CB.

When a `SELECT` uses such an index, it checks both the CB and the real, on-disk, BTree for the index.  That BTree is cached (block by block) in the buffer_pool.  (A block is 16KB and may hold hundred(s) of entries.)

The CB is flushed to disk "in the background" or "as needed".  That involves fetching an index block (unless already cached), updating some entries (delete, and/or add), and write back to disk.  Both the read and write are cached in the buffer_pool, so either or neither may be a physical I/O.

MySQL does not "rebuild" a regular index ("reindex") except via certain `ALTERs` or `OPTIMIZE`.  That is, all changes are made on the fly.  The action of the CB is transparent to the user.